syncing time between client and server
hi i am trying to sync time between my javascript server and client. I send time in miliseconds that passed since epoch and compare it to miliseconds since epoch on client, then i add difference to local time. My problem is when i run client on android sim card internet and run some downloading to make it more lagier for tests anytime i receive time from server the difference is very different. sometimes difference is 20 and sometimes 200. what should i do now. how i know which difference should i add to local time. should calculate average and apply it? what is most accurate option for me.

Why aren't all your machines running NTP so they synchronize with a central time server?

There's no excuse these days for any machine not maintaining time automatically. All consumer operating systems do it.
